# Commercial statistics webapp similar to Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, statistics

I'm looking for some service similar to Google Analytics and with a better privacy policy than Google's services.

Can someone please recommend some good commercial webapps for website statistics. My needs are not that demanding, only need the most basic of service, but hopefully as real time as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative is self hosting.

[Piwik](http://piwik.org/) is quite well done and there is a really good development team around it.

Comment: Tested Piwik and I liked it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

See this question: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/427/what-are-the-best-user-data-collection-and-gathering-tracking-tools

And you also check:

1. [Reinvigorate](http://www.reinvigorate.net/)
2. [Observer](http://observerapp.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The web app [Woopra](http://www.woopra.com). Been a user since it was in beta and it is really good. I don't know how it compares to Google Analytics, but you can use the site, a desktop app or an iPhone app to view visits and stats. Very stable. Free for less than 30k visits pr. months, then various plans above that, not unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Mint](http://haveamint.com/). You need to host it yourself though

Answer (score 0):

If you're not willing to self-host, your best bet is Google Analytics.  Nothing else comes close in terms of availability (many of the other services are too bogged down/slow to get all traffic).  For self-hosted situations, I've simply used awstats.  Not as pretty as Google, but it's nice for small sites (those with < ~500,000 visits per month).

Comment: No problem hosting it myself.

Comment: awstats is pretty good then ... nice, simple, fast, etc.